# Will MySQL table need re-indexing when new records are inserted?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, optimization, indexing

Do I need to re-index the MySQL table if I insert new records into it? Table has existing indexes.

Answer (score 0):

No, because indexes are updated automatically on any change.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL won't need to re-index the entire table when you insert a new record.  It will however need to create an index entry for your newly inserted record.

There is therefore a slight performance impact in creating indexes on tables, in that inserts will take slightly longer.  In most practical situations this is acceptable given the big performance improvement you get on reading data from indexed tables.

There is more information available at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html